# Compare Values on Two Spreadsheets and populate if match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This may or may not be possible. I'm trying to use some data that I've collected to create a google fusion heat map.

In Sheet 1 I have a list of cities in column A

In Sheet 2 I have the table of cities & zip codes in Texas from google with lat and long.

Ideally what I'd like to do is say if A1 exists in Sheet 2 then return zip in A2, lat in A3 and long A4.

Is that possible? I know that I can compare values and return true or false or something like that but I've never gone this far.

Comment: VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scott said, this is a classic example of VLOOKUP.

Your column values in Sheet 1, assuming they are titled "Zip," "Lat," and "Long" will be:

`=Vlookup(City_Cell, Whole_Range_On_Sheet_2, Column_of_Zip, FALSE)` for ZIP,

`=Vlookup(City_Cell, Whole_Range_On_Sheet_2, Column_of_Lat, FALSE)` for LAT,

`=Vlookup(City_Cell, Whole_Range_On_Sheet_2, Column_of_Long, FALSE)` for LONG

Comment: FWIW: `Column_of_Zip` is the relative column number in the `Whole_Range_On_Sheet_2` range and not the actual column.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. I suspect I'm doing something wrong w/ the column. I'm comparing A2 vs A2 through A1194 in the sheet Zips but it's not returning anything. Here's a screenshot of my sheet http://imgur.com/a/evpQ0 and this is of the zips sheet http://imgur.com/kJRI3Tq

Comment: Looks like your items in column A are different in each sheet.  The ones on the first sheet have "County", "FFA" and "4H" after them, while the ones on the second do not.  They have to be an EXACT match.  Also, you'll want the range in your formula to include at least column B for zip, and through columns H for the cells for longitude.

Comment: yeah I'm testing in row 2 and then I'm going to run a replace to remove FFA to autofill what I can

Comment: I found my issue. My range needed to include all of the columns. Thanks for the help.